# Kubernetes NodePort / Load Balancer / Ingress on a Multi-Master Setup: Is it necessary?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I'm fairly new to this but I'm setting up a multi-master, high availability Kubernetes cluster of at least 3 masters and a variable number of nodes. I'm trying to do this WITHOUT the use of kube-spray or any other tools, in order to learn the true ins-and-outs. I feel I have most of it down except one bit:

My understanding is:

- A NodePort allocates a port to a specific service
- A Load Balancer is an external resource that allows for external access
- An Ingress Controller allows you to configure specific paths to services and ports.

Some points about my cluster:

- The pods I deploy can run on any machine in the cluster and don't need to be externally accessible.
- My masters are also worker nodes and can run pods
- etcd runs on each master

My question is, do I need a NodePort/LB/Ingress Controller? I'm trying to understand why I would need any of the above. If a master is joined to an existing cluster alongside another master, the pods are distributed between them, right? Isn't that all I need? Please help me to understand as I feel I'm missing a key concept.

Answer (score 2):

First of all NodePort, LoadBalancer and Ingress has nothing to do with the setting up kubernetes cluster. These three are tools to expose your apps to the outside world so that you can access those apps from outside the kubernetes cluster.

There are two parts here:

1. Setting up the highly available kubernetes cluster with three masters. I have written a blog on it, how to setup a multi-master kubernetes cluster, it will give you brief idea about how to setup multi master cluster in kubernetes.

> https://velotio.com/blog/2018/6/15/kubernetes-high-availability-kubeadm

2. Now once you have your kubernetes cluster ready, you can start deploying your applications on it (pods,services etc.). Those application you deploy might needs to be exposed to outside world, for example a website hosted on your kubernetes cluster and needs to be accessed from internet. Then these NodePort, Loadbalancer or Ingress comes into the picture. The difference between NodePort, LoadBalancer and Ingress and when to use what? is explained very well in this article here.

> https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0

Hope this gives you some clarity.

EDIT: This edit is for kubeadm config file for 1.13(see comments)

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - "VIRTUAL IP"
controlPlaneEndpoint: "VIRTUAL IP"
etcd:
    external:
        endpoints:
        - https://ETCD_0_IP:2379
        - https://ETCD_1_IP:2379
        - https://ETCD_2_IP:2379
        caFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
        certFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
        keyFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
```

Comment: Many thanks Prafull! Both links were really helpful and easy to understand. A follow-up question if you don't mind.

I noticed on the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#stacked-control-plane-and-etcd-nodes
The example of the kubeadm-config.yaml file has LoadBalancer parameters that need to be filled in - how is that managed if using an Ingress Controller? I'm trying to avoid using cloud-resources where possible such as ELBs, are Ingress Controllers run on all masters?

Comment: Sure. We are here to help each other :)

Comment: That loadbalancer in config file is used to switch the request between multiple apiservers if any apiserver goes down. You dont need to use cloud provided LB for that, you can very well use keepalived which I used in my blog. If you see first link, I didn't used any cloud resources to setup multi master.

Comment: Once again, thank you - I'd seen it but couldn't make out where the Virtuak IP was generated and how that works, but I'll read up on keepalived to improve my understanding.
Thanks very much for your patience, I've never dealt with Kubernetes at this level before and am very lost. I may respond again in the hope you'll be able to help!

Comment: Sure Danzaa. If you follow the first link step by step you will be able to setup the cluster. If you face any issue, just respond here. I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Prafull, with your help I've automated a working, dynamically created etcd cluster!
Regarding keepalived, I've set the virtual_ip as the eth0 IP for each master - is that correct? I ask because the rest of the tutorial, around the config.yml section suggests a single IP that needs to be input into the <load-balancer-ip> value and I'm not sure how to read it. Just a little more of your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The virtual IP should be some other IP which you are not using, it can be any dummy IP . Suppose your three masters have IP 10.6.38.83, 10.6.38.84 and 10.6.38.85. Then you can have the virtual IP 10.6.35.87 on which keepalived will run. Any request comes on the virtual IP will be sent to one of the master IP.

Comment: Keepalived all set up :)

Last question (I hope!) your config.yaml for Kubernetes produces this message on kubeadm init:
Your configuration file uses an old API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1". Please use kubeadm v1.11 instead and run 'kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml', which will write the new, similar spec using a newer API version.

I've searched but can't seem to find what value I need to change, do you know?

Comment: Are you using kubernete 1.11 to setup the cluster or 1.10.3 to setup cluster. If you're using 1.11 kubadm.conf is a bit different and you can migrate it using `kubeadm config migrate --old-config <my_config.yaml> --new-config new.yaml`

Comment: I ran the command and it just produced an empty file (I did point it to the correct config.yaml

kubectl version gives:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.0", GitCommit:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-03T21:04:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: So you're using version 1.13, my blog is written on 1.10.3. Anyways, you can try the config file I am updating in the answer.

Comment: Prafull, I think your example would need some other configuration elsewhere, when I run 'kubeadm init --config=/etc/kubernetes/config.yaml' I get:

[ERROR ExternalEtcdVersion]: Get https://172.31.41.207:2379/version: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

However, doing an HTTP call I get the correct response, if I change the endpoints to HTTP it says: [etcd.external.endpoints: Invalid value: "http://172.31.41.207:2379": the URL must be using the HTTPS scheme